# Select checkbox if text is contained in the ul

Tags: c#, html, checkbox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to check/uncheck the marked with blue checkbox on the image. The catch is that I have to check if the checkbox is from list with curtain label in it. 
My script have to do something like this:

1. Navigate to the settings. (Dune)
2. Get the names of all menus. (Dune)
3. Uncheck option from first menu, save and check if this option is hidden from the menu.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2MsV.png)

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(subspace_name, subspace) in modules">
 <h4 style="width: 50%; text-align: center;">Accounting</h4>
 <div class="documenter_sidebar" style="width: 50%;">
  <ul style="padding: 0;" data-ng-repeat="module in subspace">
   <li>
    <div class="menuWrapper">
     <span class="text-modify btn-fake btn btn-xs menuParentBtn   documenter_top" style="margin-left:0;width:100%;"> Articles Expenses </span>
    </div>
    <ul style="padding: 0;" data-ng-repeat="actionName in modulesActions[subspace_name][module]">
     <li>
      <div class="menuWrapper">
       <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
         <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-model="restrictedActions[subspace_name][module][actionName]">
        </span>
        <a class="input-group-addon text-modify btn btn-xs menuParentBtn documenter_top" ng-click="restrictedActions[subspace_name][module][actionName] = !restrictedActions[subspace_name][module][actionName]" style="width:100%; margin-left:0; text-align: left;"> Add </a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="padding: 0;" data-ng-repeat="actionName in modulesActions[subspace_name][module]">
    <ul style="padding: 0;" data-ng-repeat="actionName in modulesActions[subspace_name][module]">
    <ul style="padding: 0;" data-ng-repeat="actionName in modulesActions[subspace_name][module]">
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul style="padding: 0;" data-ng-repeat="module in subspace">
  <ul style="padding: 0;" data-ng-repeat="module in subspace">
  <ul style="padding: 0;" data-ng-repeat="module in subspace">
  <ul style="padding: 0;" data-ng-repeat="module in subspace">
  <ul style="padding: 0;" data-ng-repeat="module in subspace">
  <ul style="padding: 0;" data-ng-repeat="module in subspace">
 </div>
</div>





using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class First_test
    {
        //static variables
        static int row = 1;
        static int column = 1;
        static string OurXpath = "//form[@id='editUserForm']/div/div[2]/ng-include/div[" + row + "]/div/ul[" + column + "]/li/div/span";

        //checking element present
        private bool IsElementPresent(By by)

        {
            try
           {
                driver.FindElement(by);
                return true;
           }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        IWebDriver driver;
        [SetUp]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
              driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }
        [Test]
        public void OpenAppTest()
        {

            driver.Url = "***********";
            //Login
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("****");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("****");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("login-submit")).Click();
            //Navigating to Users menu
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Users")).Click();
            //Navigate to User with id
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("edit-btn-354")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Modules Privileges")).Click();
            List<string> ModuleNames = new List<string>();
            //Adding all privileges to list
            List<string> elementTexts = new List<string>(driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("[class*='text-modify btn-fake btn btn-xs menuParentBtn documenter_top']")).S‌​elect(iw => iw.Text));
            string sample = elementTexts[1];
            Console.WriteLine(sample);
            //This is the point where I'm unable to access the element I want to. I know that this part is searching for the /li in the /span. I cant figure out how to search in privious child of that /ul
           driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[contains(span,'"+sample+"')]/li[1]")).Click();
           //This is for check if finding menus is working right.
           elementTexts.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0}\t", i));
        }
        [TearDown]
        public void EndTest()
        {
            driver.Quit();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code (as text not image).

Comment: please share the selenium C# code that you tried and the exception trace that you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code:

```
IWebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Articles Expenses')]/../../ul[1]/li/div/div/span/input")); /*select first element/checkbox from the first menu i.e., Articles Expenses */
if (element.Selected) /* if checkbox is already selected */
{
    element.Click(); /* uncheck the checkbox if already selected */
}
```

Comment: Is there any other method different from "contains", that can be used to check if the text is exactly the same. Because if I want to count the ul elements and lets say my span text is 'Articles Expenses' and it have 5 ul elements. If I have other span with text  'Articles Expenses Types' that have 3 elements. The count method will give me the sum of this two spans that contain text 'Articles Expenses'. 
      int count = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'" + SettingToCheck + "')]/../../ul")).Count;

Comment: you can use as follows: `//span[text()='texttocheck']/../../ul/.`.

Comment: First time i tried, it did not worked. An hour later I found that for some reason html file where this text is accepts the new lines before and after the text for "space". 
Thank you again for your help.